# PHP: Empty/Null and if logic inquiry

Tags: php

I have an input box that with php will echo out names typed in. The problem is that when the user presses space it will echo out the blank character. I have searched and didnt find an absolute answer. I know that using `!empty` if there is absoutely anthing in the input field but if there is a space is null supposed to work.

How to avoid getting echo if there is blank space in input?

```
if (!empty($name['name']) || null ) {
    echo 'Your name is '.$name;

}
{

//do nothing 

}
```

Comment: It's generally suggested to use [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) on inputs like these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calls to the function `empty()` will be true if it is unset, null, empty string, boolean false, or 0.  Still I like avoiding heavy logic in conditionals... pull out the trimming and prepping the string before testing.

```
$nameString = empty($name['name'])?null:trim($name['name']);
if(!empty($nameString){
    //go to town here
}
```

To appease the fanatics in advance, I have to also add that you should escape any user input before printing it.  That way you protect against XSS.  To be safer add try this:

```
$nameString = empty($name['name'])?null:trim($name['name']);
$nameString = htmlentities($nameString, ENT_QUOTES);
if(!empty($nameString){
    //go to town here
}
```

However, a side note... the `htmlentities()` call does not protect against SQL injection, so if this data is going into a db you'll have to do more work--since your question doesn't indicate you're doing anything else than printing out to screen, we can hold off the SQL injection discussion for another day.

Comment: Very well explained! I was having difficulties wrapping my head around empty, null, trim, etc but now is much clearer. But yes i will store them in DB and will look into avoiding sql injections.

Comment: @cholomanCoding just don't store your htmlentity escaped string in the db directly... create a second string from the original to protect and store or you'll get a mess of junk in your DB columns...

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if there is a space, you may want to do this:

```
if ($name['name'] != null && trim($name['name']) != "" && !strpos(trim($name['name']), " "))
{
    // work with $name['name']
}
else
{
    // nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using empty(), it will return TRUE if the user enters '0'.

You might want to use strlen()